# no addons showing up in blender 2.9 despite them being in the correct directory [SOLVED]

Tags: add-on, versions

after updating blender to 2.9 all preinstalled addons will not show up in add-ons setting page.

```
ls /usr/share/blender/2.90/scripts/addons
add_curve_extra_objects                io_anim_acclaim                   io_import_scene_unreal_psa_psk.py  materials_utils               object_cloud_gen.py            space_view3d_copy_attributes.py
add_curve_ivygen.py                    io_anim_bvh                       io_mesh_pdb                        measureit                     object_edit_linked.py          space_view3d_math_vis
add_curve_sapling                      io_anim_c3d                       io_mesh_ply                        mesh_bsurfaces.py             object_fracture                space_view3d_modifier_tools.py
add_mesh_ant_landscape.py              io_anim_camera.py                 io_mesh_raw                        mesh_carver.py                object_fracture_cell           space_view3d_pie_menus
add_mesh_BoltFactory                   io_anim_nuke_chan                 io_mesh_stl                        mesh_custom_normals_tools.py  object_grease_scatter.py       space_view3d_spacebar_menu.py
add_mesh_extra_objects                 io_blend_utils                    io_mesh_uv_layout                  mesh_f2.py                    object_print3d_utils           system_blend_info.py
animation_add_corrective_shape_key.py  io_coat3D                         io_online_sketchfab                mesh_inset                    oscurart_tools                 system_demo_mode
animation_animall.py                   io_convert_image_to_mesh_img      io_scene_3ds                       mesh_looptools.py             paint_palette.py               system_property_chart.py
archimesh                              io_curve_svg                      io_scene_fbx                       mesh_relax.py                 pie_menus_official             ui_layer_manager.py
blender_id                             io_export_after_effects.py        io_scene_ms3d                      mesh_tiny_cad                 presets                        ui_translate
bone_selection_sets.py                 io_export_dxf                     io_scene_obj                       mocap                         __pycache__                    uv_bake_texture_to_vcols.py
curve_simplify.py                      io_export_pc2.py                  io_scene_vrml2                     modules                       render_auto_tile_size.py       uv_texture_atlas.py
cycles                                 io_export_unreal_psk_psa.py       io_scene_x                         netrender                     render_copy_settings
development_api_navigator.py           io_import_dxf                     io_scene_x3d                       node_wrangler.py              render_freestyle_svg.py
development_icon_get.py                io_import_gimp_image_to_scene.py  io_sequencer_edl                   object_add_chain.py           render_povray
game_engine_publishing.py              io_import_images_as_planes.py     io_shape_mdd                       object_animrenderbake.py      rigify
game_engine_save_as_runtime.py         io_import_scene_lwo.py            light_field_tools                  object_boolean_tools.py       space_view3d_3d_navigation.py
```

[image: no_add-ons_in_blender2.9]

Comment: In blenders python console type in `bpy.utils.script_paths('addons')` It will echo a list of folders where blender looks for addons.

Comment: Are you using Arch Linux?

Comment: yes im using arch linux btw and the ouput of that cmd was `['/usr/share/blender/2.90/scripts/addons']` witch is the same as shown above.

Comment: The Arch package wasn't properly build, see [T80553](https://developer.blender.org/T80553) and ticket on the [Arch bug tracker](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/67792?project=0&order=id&sort=desc&status%5B0%5D=closed&string=blender). You can also download the releases directly from Blender's website.

Comment: ran yay and its patched now.